# Problem with foreach loop in tikzpicture - undefined control sequence

Tags: pgfplots, foreach, nodes-near-coords

I am puzzled by something in tikzpicture.
Here is the problematic code that i shrinked to its minimum:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Table}{
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
\foreach \A / \B/ \C   in {1/100/g, 2/200/h}
    \addplot [
    mark=diamond*,
    nodes near coords={g}] 
    coordinates {(\B, \A)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\Table

\end{document}
```

This code works well and adds the label *g* next to the markers.
But i would like this label to be a variable in the foreach loop.
So i replace
`nodes near coords={g}` by `nodes near coords={\C}`

But then I got an 'undefined control sequence' error.
Could someone explain why is this the case? And also possible way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unrelated: `pgfplotstable` loads `pgfplots`, `pgfplots` loads `tikz` and `tikz` loads `xcolor`. So, it is sufficient to just load the `pgfplotstable` package. But you should add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` as noted in a warning you should get.

Comment: The problem here is that PGFPlots doesn't “execute” the `\addplot`s directly (or at least not all of it) but caches things for later. At that point `\C` isn't either defined anymore (because `\foreach` groups its body) or `\C` is just the last item (when a loop is used that doesn't group its body).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Could you elaborate or direct me to documentation for what "groups its body" means? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- The node is drawn later and then `\C` will be unknown. Therefore, you can use the option `visualization depends on`:

  ```
  visualization depends on={value \C\as\myC},
  nodes near coords={\myC}
  ```

  - I found the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492608/123129).
- Implemented suggestions from [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927)'s comment

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Table}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \A / \B / \C in {1/100/g, 2/200/h}
                \addplot[
                    mark=diamond*,
                    visualization depends on={value \C\as\myC},
                    nodes near coords={\myC}
                ] 
                coordinates {(\B, \A)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\Table

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, I would have a follow up question as this methods does not appear to work for colors of the marker. I tried to go back at my initial code that has a few more features and just adding the colors variable with the same methods seems to cause a problem. Should i create a separate post or is there a way to create follow up questions?

Comment: It would be best to ask a new question, with the code you tried and provide a link to this question/answer for reference.

Comment: Thanks, this done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695921/problem-with-tikzpicture-and-colors-in-a-eachloop-loop).