# Problem with Tikzpicture and colors in a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, undefined

I am following on one of [my previous questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695833/problem-with-foreach-loop-in-tikzpicture-undefined-control-sequence) regarding the use of foreach loop in tikzpicture:

Here is a simple description with a code that works but with all markers colored in red:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Table}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \A / \B/ \C  in {1/100/green, 2/200/red}
                \addplot [
                    mark=diamond*,
                    color=red
                ] 
                coordinates {(\B, \A)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\Table

\end{document}
```

In my case, i would like to make the color a variable in the foreach loop. I tried to adapt a methods that was suggested succesfully for marker label in my previous question. So i changed `color=red` for

```
visualization depends on={value \C\as\myC},
color={\myC}
```

But in that case it does not compile and return a 'undefined control sequence' error.
I would be interested to understand the reason behin such problem, and possible way to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have specified as a command that replacing 'color=red' by 'color={\C}' yield an error "undefined control sequence". This is why i used the 'visualization depends on' trick suggested earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an answer based on [This solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353789/change-color-of-addplot-in-a-foreach-loop-pgfplots). It worked after adding the commands `edef`,`temp` and `noexpand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Table}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \A / \B/ \C  in {1/100/green, 2/200/red,  3/300/blue} {%
            \edef\temp{%
                \noexpand
                \addplot [
                    mark=diamond*,
                    color=\C,
                ] 
                coordinates {(\B, \A)};
                }\temp
                }   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\Table
\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image]

Comment: +1 Do you know why it works? I also wonder (if) there isn't a simpler solution. (That's not a criticism. I even tried reading the documentation but didn't get anywhere.)

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not savvy with latex macros or `pgfplots`. From what I can understand from the documentation (page 547 of `pgfplots` manual), `pgfplots` does not evaluate the code that you write sequentially, but for some things it waits until it finds the `end{axis}` command. This produces a "crash", as loops must be evaluated where they are, not at the end of everything. Thus, the code that is added in the answer forces `pgfplots` to evaluate the loop without waiting. But take this with a grain of salt!

Comment: In this way, and from my understanding, `noexpand` tells `pgfplots` to wait, `edef` forces it to "go searching" for the value of the color and `temp` I have no idea, to be honest. I found a little bit of info here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_does_%5Cexpandafter_work%3A_The_meaning_of_expansion

Comment: The Overleaf link is really useful - thanks! (I have an extremely fuzzy conception of expansion. More like a mental haze than a concept.)

Comment: It is still unclear to me why this works, but it does work! Thanks so much.