# pgfplots: `visualization depends on` works only when assigning a new macro name

Tags: pgfplots

Using a simplified version of an older [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695839) as MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \A / \B / \C in {1/100/g, 2/200/h}
                \addplot[
                 mark=diamond*,
                 visualization depends on={value \C\as\myC},
                 nodes near coords={\myC}
                ]
                    coordinates {(\B, \A)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as intended. But, according to the manual, I should also be able to just specify the macro the save instead of assigning it a new name. So:

```
                \addplot[
                 mark=diamond*,
                 visualization depends on={value \C},
                 nodes near coords={\C}
                ]
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, `visualization depends on=value <
\macro>' expected a defined control sequence name instead of `\C '. Please make
 sure `\C ' is a properly defined macro or use the `visualization depends on=va
lue <content> \as<\macro>' syntax instead.
```

Why does this version fail? It looks like a space slipped into the macro name. Is this a bug?

Comment: Could be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

`visualization depends on` is used when the visualization of a point depends on more than just `point meta`. As your `\addplot` only has one point, it is not really applicable here although it does work. - see my code with and without `visualization depends on`.

What does not work is your loop - see section 8.1 in the manual about `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.
-and comment by @Qrrbrbirlbel in your linked question

> The problem here is that PGFPlots doesn't “execute” the \addplots
> directly (or at least not all of it) but caches things for later. At
> that point \C isn't either defined anymore (because \foreach groups
> its body) or \C is just the last item (when a loop is used that
> doesn't group its body).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
%\foreach \A / \B / \C in {1/100/g, 2/200/h}
\newcommand{\A}{1}
\newcommand{\B}{100}
\newcommand{\C}{g}
\addplot[
mark=diamond*,
%visualization depends on=value \C, %this also works
nodes near coords=\C
] coordinates {(\B, \A)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with a single point and label]

Comment: *As your \addplot only has one point, it is not really applicable here*

It is as `point meta` cannot store textual information.

*What does not work is your loop*

That is exactly the point why I'm using `visualization depends on`. It stores the macro content that is already out of scope. Simply removing the loop does not only change the output but also avoids the original problem, I'm afraid. (My non-reduced code absolutely needs the loop, too.)

Comment: True `point meta` does not store text, but the original macro does. When you only have one point in `\addplot` you could use the original macro except that it does not work in a loop - see my answer and the original linked question/answer. I can not explain further.